# Disable prompt to save on document close in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Is there a setting deep within Visual Studio that disables the prompt to save on closing a file/document and just auto-saves the file instead? It seems really redundant with my Git repo backing it.

Comment: @CodyGray oh i do. i just want it to autosave instead.

Comment: The only setting I know of is to autosave before building. There are a couple of extensions that might be useful, though: [NoMorePanicSave2015](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PhilippDolder.NoMorePanicSave2015) and [CBAutoSave](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ccb2010.CBAutoSave). I honestly never run into this because I obsessively Ctrl+S every few moments. It is completely subconscious now.